# get the highest numbered image tag in a remote docker repository

Tags: docker, repository

How can you remotely determine the image having the highest tag, in a remote registry?  Without having to pull down the images and look at them.  I need this to work for an authenticated connection.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Perl.  As shown here:

```
tagslist = commands.getstatusoutput("curl -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -k -s -u <U>:<P> https://docker-registry/v2/myrepo/tags/list")

n=json.dumps(tagslist)
o=json.loads(n)
m=o[1]
t=json.loads(m)
s=t['tags']
highest=-1
for i in s:
 try:
    iTag = int(i)
    if iTag > highest:
      highest=iTag
 except ValueError:
    val = 0

print highest
```

This worked well for me.  Python 2.7 on Gnu/Linux